# Can only log in via service name in SQL developer [Oracle DB]

Tags: sql, database, oracle

So I dl and installed Oracle Db 21c, the latest version. I connect to it via SQL developer using the default system account. The SID was XE when I connected using SQL developer, when I tried to make a new user I encounter an error. After searching it seems I had to alter my session to a plugable database so I alter my session to XEPDB1 and was able to successfully create the user.

Now I can connect to the DB with that user but if I use the SID of XE it says invalid login information but if I switch to service name and put XEPDB1 it works. However I have a program that populate it with the data I need but the program only takes SID for the connection. So do I find the SID I should be using to log into the new account I created?

Tried using XEPDB1 as SID but that doesn't work. I expect to be able to connect to this new user I created with an SID instead of the service name.

Comment: Not sure if you are asking to find SID information - if so, you can try using select sys_context('USERENV','SID') from dual;

Comment: So when I connect with the system account i use SID XE and it works.

But when I try to connect with another user I created it can't and have to use service name.

When I run that sql query it just give me a number and its different each time.

Comment: Check this,  - thanks to the poster @Simon Krenger  https://www.krenger.ch/blog/connect-to-a-pdb-using-sid/

Comment: Thanks! That is very helpful! I guess there no other way around it. Going to be a bit of work changing the source code that's using it.

Comment: *Technically* the use of SID as a network connection parameter has been deprecated since Oracle 9. Service Name is the only method guaranteed to work.